# Is there OPC UA .NET official API reference and documentation?

Tags: .net, opc-ua

I can't find any official docs online to describe the .NET API for OPC UA, aside from some code samples and a big specifications document.

Just want to check if there are API reference docs and guide some where for .NET platform, before I continue to study the sample code and figure out what the methods and classes do?

We need to convert some small code service from OPC classic to OPC UA, so I don't have much time to reverse-engineer code or read too much.

Answer (score 0):

There are few available :

**Unified Automation .NET OPC UA SDK API Reference.**

https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkdotnet/2.0.0/index.html

**Github**

http://opcfoundation.github.io/UA-.NETStandard/

https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard

https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NET-Legacy  (Deprecated now)

Unified Architecture:
https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/specifications-unified-architecture/

Comment: Thanks! You're a life saver, not sure why the docs are in another website and there is no reference from OPC Foundation website.

Comment: @Pranav Singh: The Unified Automation .NET OPC UA SDK is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: Hmm, now that I checked the link again, yeah it's not the same thing. :(

Answer (score 0):

Except from Source code documentation, there are also  [Getting Started](http://opcfoundation.github.io/UA-.NETStandard/) guides.

Based on what your sample example are doing it could be also necessary to read the [OPC UA Specification](https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/specifications-unified-architecture).

Sorry: my mistake the Getting Started link was already provided... you can use docfx to generate the API Reference Documentation from source code. There is not more available.

[2nd Edit] Did you consider just using a generic Classic OPC to OPC UA wrapper instead of rewrite? It can save you alot of time. See [UA-.Net Standard Library COM Server Wrapper](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/blob/master/ComIOP/README.md)